# dropped it on the "ground"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> He came out onto the roof with a bottle of whisky in his hand. He took a gulp from it, then accidentally dropped it on the ground where it shattered.

Is "ground" okay if he is on a roof or would you avoid it?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? He can drop it from the roof on the ground. But, generally, when you drop something on the ground, you are standing on the ground or near it, not up on a rood....

Comment: What I mean is that he drops it on the roof, not off it.

Comment: @Lambie I think what's being described in these lines is "he" is drinking on a rooftop or roof deck and drops the bottle on the surface of the rooftop.

Comment: Ok, if you are on the roof and drop it on the roof, it is not ground. But now I am explaining this **again**. Mind you, a roof can also be flat....

Answer (score 1):

The ground is the ground,  not the roof.  If you say he was on the roof and he dropped the bottle "on the ground", I'd imaging him dropping it off the roof.

So if you don't mean "on the ground" you should just say

> ...then accidentally dropped it, and it shattered.

You might say something like "dropped it on the shingles, where it shattered". If it is a shingled roof.